# Python datetime.strptime - ValueError: time data does not match format

Tags: python, datetime

I am new in Python. I try write program who will read from file and write it to database. There is part of my code :

```
import datetime

format = '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S '
mytime = '[29/Oct/2017:13:11:38 '
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, format)
```

When I run script I have this error :

```
 now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '[29/Oct/2017:13:11:38 ' does not match format '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S '
```

I dont understood this mistake. It match format. There is no extra space or anything like that. And I use this 2 lines of code

```
format = '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S '
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, format)
```

in another program and it works fine. Where is problem ?

Comment: %I ? you mean `'[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S '` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), `%I` matches hours for times in AM/PM format, meaning valid values range from 01 to 12. You have 13 (1 PM)

I guess you need to use `%H`

```
import datetime

mytime = '[29/Oct/2017:13:11:38 '
fmt = '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S '
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, fmt)
print("now: %s" % now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

prints:

```
now: 2017-10-29 13:11:38
```

Check this:

```
fmt = '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S '

for test in range(1, 24):
    mytime = '[29/Oct/2017:%02d:11:38 ' % test
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, fmt)
    print("now: %s" % now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Will work "fine" (I quote because `12` is assumed to be midnight) until `test` hits `13`:

```
now: 2017-10-29 01:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 02:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 03:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 04:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 05:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 06:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 07:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 08:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 09:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 10:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 11:11:38
now: 2017-10-29 00:11:38
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack_096.py", line 12, in <module>
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, fmt)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '[29/Oct/2017:13:11:38 ' does not match format '[%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S '
```

Comment: which explains that it worked in another program (by luck!=

Comment: good point. I edited to add a more detailed explanation on where it'd break